# Wicket: Accessing the FileUploadFile selected file

Tags: javascript, java, wicket

I have a FileUploadField on a form. This component adds the following element to the HTML

```
<input id="upload" type="file" name="fileUpload">
```

When clicked, the user must select a file. I want to know what the name of that file is, immediately after selection, so I can set the values of other components on the form.

I tried attaching an "onChange" AjaxEvenBehaviour to the FileUploadField, but can't see the filename in the request parameters.

```
    FileUploadField fileUpload = new FileUploadField("fileUpload");

    form.add(fileUpload);

    fileUpload.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onChange") {

        @Override
        protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            Request request = RequestCycle.get().getRequest();
            request.getRequestParameters();

        }

    });
```

Has anyone successfully done this, and how did you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to instruct the behavior to send along the value of the input:

```
fileUpload.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("change") {

    @Override
    protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes)
    {
        super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);

        String value = "return {'value': Wicket.$(attrs.c).value}";
        attributes.getDynamicExtraParameters().add(value);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        Request request = RequestCycle.get().getRequest();

        request.getRequestParameters().getParameterValue("value");

    }

});
```

Comment: I couldn't get the event firing with the above code on Wicket 6.x.

When I changed the event name from "onChange" to "change" the event firing started working.

Comment: Actually nowadays all event names have to be specified without the on-prefix, I adjusted the sample code. Thanks.